# How do I change dates to strings in R?

Tags: r, string, date, types

I have a massive column of dates with time. I want to change it to “BP” for before pandemic and “AP” for after pandemic depending on the date. Any date after 2020-04-20 would be AP and anything before is BP.

I tried using `gsub` to change it and the `ifelse` function but that did not work.

The format of the date is `yyyy-mm-dd` `hh-mm-ss`. The type is double.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
my_data <- data.frame(
  date = as.POSIXct(c(
  "2020-04-01 12:34:56",
  "2020-04-21 01:23:45"))
)
my_data
#>                  date
#> 1 2020-04-01 12:34:56
#> 2 2020-04-21 01:23:45

# create a new variable called pandemic
my_data$pandemic = ifelse(my_data$date >= as.POSIXct("2020-04-20 00:00:00"),
                          "AP",
                          "BP")
my_data
#>                  date pandemic
#> 1 2020-04-01 12:34:56       BP
#> 2 2020-04-21 01:23:45       AP
```

Or if you really want to overwrite the `date` column and change to a character type, use:

```r
my_data$date = ifelse(my_data$date >= as.POSIXct("2020-04-20 00:00:00"),
                     "AP", "BP")
my_data
#>   date
#> 1   BP
#> 2   AP
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the dataset, the packages [`fasttime`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fasttime/index.html), [`anytime`](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html), or [`lubridate`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) might be useful!

Comment: Jon creates a new variable called `pandemic` in the code `my_data$pandemic <- ifelse(...`, see also also basic usage of data.frames (the dollar sign access a variable in the data.frame).

Comment: @David So my understanding of the `$` is that like you said it accesses a variable in the data frame. But from what you are saying `my_data$pandemic` created that new variable. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: That is correct! See also [R-tutor](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame) on data.frames. You might also want to see [`data.table`](https://r-datatable.com) or [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) if you handle data.frames more often (or larger dataframes).